# Msmq authentication from asp.net site

Tags: security, msmq

If you have an asp.net site sending messages to a remote queue, how do you handle authentication. If Windows Authentication is turned off, the network service sends a message to the remote queue. Does that mean that in de security tab of the queue, I need to add the netwerk service of the server sending the message? (by the way, I do not use http or https).

And what if Windows Authentication is enabled, do I need to add all users that will log in using windows authentication to the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ASP.NET site is running with the default ASP.NET user (on IIS 7.5 this will be `IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName`.

This account (or the different accounts used on earlier versions of IIS) has no access to network resources. But you can change the IIS App Pool to run under a domain account which can then access remote resources.

Note you will need to ensure the account has access to all necessary local resources.

In a workgroup you need a local account on each of the two machines with same name and password.

Comment: Is that safe, running the IIS App Pool under a domain account?

Comment: Yes. Of course some of the security speed bumps are lost, so if your app is hacked/exploited the damage *could* be worse. Like all security it is a trade off, and I assume you would rather avoid security issues. If the MSMQ queue is writeable without authentication then that also creates its own vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is not much security here - the SID can easily be spoofed in a message. Using certificates is the preferred route if security is a real requirement.

Cheers

John Breakwell

Comment: Can I find some detailed information on these certificates?

Comment: Very sorry about the delay - did you find the information you needed?